# Laravel 5.3 How to avoid locale before prefix in api routes in multilanguage app?

Tags: php, laravel, routes, laravel-5.3

I've built a multilanguage app in Laravel 5.3 and I have a bunch of api routes that return me some resources where the url is something like this `http://app-domain.com/api/resource` when I'm on my default language.

The problem presents itself when I'm not in the default language. When the app tries to call the api it sends a request to `http://app-domain.com/locale/api/resource` which returns nothing since it's not the correct path.

My implementation is very simple, just basic routing in my `routes/api.php`

```
Route::group([
    'prefix' => 'api'
  ],function() {
    Route::get('resource', 'ApiController@getResource')->name('get-resource');
});
```

Then I'm using jquery ajax object to call it

```
$.get( "api/resource", function( data ) {
  //run somecode
});
```

How can I address this problem and have my api routes resolving correctly no matter the language? Is there some params that I can set in the routes to prevent this? I've been looking in the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/routing) but found nothing relevant.

P.S.: I'm using [Mcmanamara Laravel Localization](https://github.com/mcamara/laravel-localization)

Comment: You should post your current implementation.

Comment: Your issue is not from laravel, but wherever you call your api from. Because, that's where the URL is being changed.

Comment: I'm just calling the default route in my ajax request setting the url param to `api/resource`. I guess I could catch the full url and do some string magic to call the correct route but that seems like a workaround. I wonder if there's another option.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO for setting locale its better if you use a query-string: i.e.:

http://app-domain.com/api/resource?locale=en

For two, valid, reasons:

1) The locale in the querystring could also be non existing, so you can fallback to default locale.

2) Having a locale parameter in a route could conflict with other routes parameters generating a lot of confusion